# Community Promotion Ads — 2020

Tags: discussion, community-ads

You lost your “beta” label in 2019, so welcome to your very first edition of **Community Promotion Ads**, for the year of 2020!

#### What are Community Promotion Ads?

Community Promotion Ads are community-vetted advertisements that will show up on the main site, in the right sidebar. The purpose of this question is the vetting process. Images of the advertisements are provided, and community voting will enable the advertisements to be shown.

#### Why do we have Community Promotion Ads?

This is a method for the community to control what gets promoted to visitors on the site. For example, you might promote the following things:

- interesting blogs
- helpful resources on the subject matter
- cool events or conferences
- anything else your community would genuinely be interested in

The goal is for future visitors to find out about *the stuff your community deems important*. This also serves as a way to promote information and resources that are *relevant to your own community's interests*, both for those already in the community and those yet to join.

#### Why do we reset the ads every year?

Some services will maintain usefulness over the years, while other things will wane to allow for new faces to show up. Resetting the ads every year helps accommodate this, and allows old ads that have served their purpose to be cycled out for fresher ads for newer things. This helps keep the material in the ads relevant to not just the subject matter of the community, but to the current status of the community. We reset the ads once a year, every December.

The community promotion ads have no restrictions against reposting an ad from a previous cycle. If a particular service or ad is very valuable to the community and will continue to be so, it is a good idea to repost it. It may be helpful to give it a new face in the process, so as to prevent the imagery of the ad from getting stale after a year of exposure.

#### How does it work?

The answers you post to this question *must* conform to the following rules, or they will be ignored.

1. All answers should be in the exact form of:

   ```
   [![Tagline to show on mouseover][1]][2]

      [1]: http://image-url
      [2]: http://clickthrough-url
   ```

   Please **do not add anything else to the body of the post**. If you want to discuss something, do it in the comments.
2. The question must always be tagged with the magic [community-ads](/questions/tagged/community-ads) tag. In addition to enabling the functionality of the advertisements, this tag also pre-fills the answer form with the above required form.

#### Image requirements

- The image that you create must be 300 x 250 pixels, or double that if high DPI.
- Must be hosted through our standard image uploader (imgur)
- Must be GIF or PNG
- No animated GIFs
- Absolute limit on file size of 150 KB
- If the background of the image is white or partially white, there must be a 1px border (2px if high DPI) surrounding it.

#### Score Threshold

There is a **minimum score threshold** an answer must meet (currently **6**) before it will be shown on the main site.

You can check out the ads that have met the threshold with basic click stats [here](https://history.meta.stackexchange.com/ads/display/4045).

Comment: Right now the referenced basic [stats](https://history.meta.stackexchange.com/ads/display/4045) is a null set, which makes voting easy, but I don't think the voting will result in actionable information.  Who markets advertising? Who is responsible for proposing new ad opportunities? How does this work?

Comment: Who provides the art?  Us, or the advertiser?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your questions — the community is "responsible" for all the things you mentioned, if I got you right. Though I say "responsible" (between quotation marks) because it's completely optional if you use this space or not. Does that answer your questions? :)

Comment: I guess I just don't understand how to nominate an advertiser. If I think it would be a good idea to advertise British History Podcast, or Guns Germs & Steel, do I create my own art? Steal art from their website?  Do I need their permission to advertise their goods/services?

Comment: I think a link to another site that's already doing this so we can see what both the process and the results look like could be helpful. We've been beta so long we are super new to this.

Comment: [Here](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7063/8555)'s an example of how ads look, from last year's Worldbuilding post — hope that helps, @T.E.D.

Comment: That is very helpful - the question seems to describe commercial advertisement; the example you provide is marketing. While there is some overlap, they are very distinct.  Thanks for the help

Comment: Hmmmm. If I'm grokking this, it looks like what we *should* be doing is making a nice pretty ad for ourselves, and trying to drop it in this meta thread on *other* sites' metas.

Comment: That would be a good thing to do, yes, @T.E.D. — as long as it's relevant for _those_ sites :)

Comment: Lemme know if there are other things I can help clarify, @MarkC.Wallace :)

Comment: If I understand this correctly. If the ad we endorse here is shown on our own main site: I think we need an ad for Meta-History.SE the most?

Comment: Other communities do post ads to invite users to participate on their Metas, yes, @LаngLаngС :)

Comment: Is there a limit to the number of these ads we can display or is there a rotation schedule used if more than a certain number are created and all meet your criteria?

Comment: See the comments [here](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5551/community-promotion-ads-2019?noredirect=1&lq=1#comment17170_5551) for some info on that, @justCal :) But there's no limit to the number of posts here, or the ads that can make it above the 6-vote threshold.

Comment: We had a few [preliminary ideas discussed here](https://history.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4047/brainstorming-community-promotion-ads). Could you comment a bit on those? (For me the big GIFs are broken when rescaled by imgur to (any) size. Is that a general bug or more probably on my [Safari] end?)

Comment: Broken how, @LаngLаngС?