# Brainstorming Community Promotion Ads

Tags: discussion

Since the [Community Promotion Ad](https://history.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4045/16951) question seems to be for final products only, I thought perhaps we might have a discussion question concerning what types of 'ads' we might wish to see.  It looks like this may be an opportunity for some of those messages we would like to get out to prospective users, and perhaps we can crowdsource here what might make for effective use of our 'ad' space. Perhaps post an answer describing a concept and then comments,edits and votes to select or help fine tune favorites?

Some other ideas someone might run with:

- **Holocaust question? click here first.**  With link to meta discussion explaining our higher standards  on holocaust questions.
- **Homework Question?** {possible second line *Don't ask*} -link to a meta discussion showing why we can't do their homework for them,
- **New User, Take the tour**
- **Don't forget to accept the best answer** I've seen this one somewhere else...
- **Nazi Troll??  Go Away** with the required Indiana Jones poster (OK,this one might be taken as a challenge[counterproductive] or might
  not meet our 'friendly' community standards...)
- **Keep your *isms* to yourself** over word cloud of nazism, sexism, racism, ... with a link explaining push questions
- **Visit meta, help define the rules!** image of blind justice, or scales of law
- **Want a book recommendation, ask a Librarian** with link to source requests being off topic

You can see there are quite a few issues we deal with *repetitively* here, which an occasional 'ad' helping to pre-inform users of policies or possible issues might just improve the site flow.

Answer (score 4):

- Text: **First Question? Learn how here.**
- Text: **Have a Question?  Make it a good one.**

with a link to the [ask] page in help.

No idea on graphics, perhaps a page full of question marks, 
or a 'Question' mark made up of the 5Ws as a word cloud similar to [this](https://k12.thoughtfullearning.com/sites/k12/files/minilesson/images/shutterstock_123605941.jpg):

[image]

Might even break it up with a few of the most popular history 'tags'...
[image]

(file size is a little too big though @211K)

[image]

A better background, but way too big (600K). By the time I shrink it  I get to 178K (still too big) and (mostly) unreadable.

[image]

Just a possible concept. Perhaps we have some members better at graphic arts who can make a better version?

For resources I used an online [word cloud generator](https://www.wordclouds.com/), and found a [parchment/old paper background](https://pixabay.com/photos/paper-old-texture-parchment-1074131/) at [Pixabay](https://pixabay.com/). The cloud words are the first four pages of our [site tags](https://history.stackexchange.com/tags).

Comment: While I really dislike ads in general, this one needs to be targeted at *potential* first time askers or other noobs. It only makes sense if that can be determined before its loaded and shown, depending on the viewer?

Comment: I'm picturing these as more community service announcements. I like your suggestion in  the other thread concerning visiting meta.  I could see similar graphics concerning why did I get a downvote, what to do if your question is closed, ect. All pointing to relevant meta links.

Comment: That's how I understand them best as well. But can they be targeted like that?

Comment: I asked on the other thread, and it looks like no limit to how many, but they would be randomly rotated is my understanding. (unless we narrow it down/accept a limited number) Hence my question here.

Comment: For something like this one, if we can get the new users each day just to look first, it may eliminate some problems later that we have to explain,  fix or delete.

Comment: The word cloud thing is just unsuitable. Too much visual clutter, resulting in way too high filesize, especially when 'made old'.Nice idea, but given the parameters.  — I'd like to see sth like an old Dutch master leafing through book pages; with a turban & pearl earring…  (or maybe just sth like TheHonRose's avatar?), then added a upto3 word Q or instructions?

Comment: Ya, I agree, the word cloud thing is too, well wordy...It was just a concept anyways, I'm by no means a graphic artist

Answer (score 3):

The only ads which I would like to see on this cite would be ones aimed at improving our content. So, following on from *justCal*'s suggestion, how about...

Text:

**Have an answer to a question?**

**Great! Please help improve our site by giving sources.**

(or something similar.)

Graphic: perhaps a simplified / less cluttered version of something like this below (with some modifications, e.g. an ancient inscription and / or a medieval painting and / or a 19th century cartoon and / or WWII archive material and / or a webpage and / or a book etc.)

[image]

*Source: [University of South Australia](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IRCHdhdS_aU)*

Comment: Definitely an important one! Text could even be limited to 'Good answers need Good Sources'.(I'm not sure how much text and font sizes fit yet) Other possible graphic elements stack of old books, maps,  lecturer at podium.

Comment: @justCal 'Good answers need Good Sources' - yes, snappier, I like it.

Comment: Ahem, I do *not* get this picture. "help us by linking to frakbook, blogs, and bob's page…"? Or do I just fail to recognise a deeply frowning face on that figure? (And *nothing* related to WW2 needs any ads here…). The pic *absolutely needs* modifications, on all levels?

Comment: @LаngLаngС Like I said, the obviously inappropriate bits (like Fcbk) would be replaced with (maybe) some of the suggestions I made (and justCal added a few good ones). I agree that while WWII doesn't need advertising here, the quality of answers (WWII or otherwise) does.

Answer (score 2):

The three nudges I'd like to see most would be along those lines, numbered for feedback:

## 1. First question? Learn how to ask it here:

[image: First question? Learn how to ask it here.]

- Nicolaes Maes’s masterpiece … Girl at a Window 1653-5 (detail). Photograph: Nicolaes Maes/Rijksmuseum, Amsterdam
- 600x500 pixels, 142k GIF (although that size only 'works' with reduced colour palette)

## 2. Visit meta, help define the rules!

[image: Visit meta, help define the rules!]

- Using [La Constitution de 1791.jpg](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/9/9f/La_Constitution_de_1791.jpg)
- 600x500 pixels, filesize 101k GIF (here palette reduction works amazingly well)

## 3. History answers give sources and references

[image: History answers give sources and references]

- Illustration of the ancient Library of Alexandria, Egypt.
- 600x500 pixels, 146k

Comment: Nice. Though it might have been better for gathering input by breaking it into individual responses.

Comment: @justCal For the moment, it seems that feedback is so limited overall that it might suffice to number the pics? But if your comment receives 2 more upvotes, I'll separate them out…

Comment: Yes, feedback was not what I was hoping, I guess the community isn't that interested in the community promotion ads...

Comment: The general idea behind all three of these seems good — I'd rework the phrasing on the third one, maybe? Some closer to a call-to-action may work better: "remember to quote your sources and references when answering" or something similar?